# What would I need to change to make this random number generator code stop when it generates the "Chosen number"?

Tags: java, computer-science

The code I am trying to execute records guesses from numbers 1 to 100 using .randomNextInt(100) + 1. It is meant to do so only until the chosen number has been generated. Then, a message with the number of tries it took to generate is created.

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class FeelingLucky {
public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random random = new Random(1);
        final int theNumber = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        
        int Tries = 1;
        System.out.print("Pick a number between 1 and 100: ");
        int theGuess = scanner.nextInt();


        while (theGuess != theNumber) {
            theGuess = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
            System.out.println(theGuess);
            Tries++;
            if (theGuess == theNumber)
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("It took " + Tries + " tries to match");
    }
}
```

I tried using the if and break statment after Tries++ to see if that would make it stop at the chosen number, however it did not seem to do anything. Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There's no problem with your code (at least not the one you mention)

Comment: *It took 85 tries to match*

Comment: And it always will. To see why, you need to look into what random *"seeding"* is

Comment: The `if` and `break` are redundant, because they are at the end of the loop. Immediately after the if statement the loop condition will be checked as the loop decides whether to run again.

Comment: @g00se or one try if the user is lucky :-)

Comment: @tgdavies Hehe: yes. 86 is my lucky number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I was able to get it. I had the "guess" and the chosen "number" switched around. I thought you were supposed to create the chosen number yourself but you were supposed to read it in from the output given in the assignment.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class FeelingLucky {
public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random random = new Random(1);
        
        int theGuess = 0;
        System.out.print("Pick a number between 1 and 100: ");
        final int theNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        
        int Tries = 0;
        while (theGuess != theNumber) {
            theGuess= random.nextInt(100) + 1;
            System.out.println(theGuess);
            Tries++;
        }

        System.out.println("It took " + Tries + " tries to match");
    }
}
```